# How should I properly use __attribute__ ((format (printf, x, y))) inside a class method in C++?

Tags: c++, gcc, printf, string-formatting

I'm trying to define a class method for debug prints that will behave like `printf`:

```
inline void debug(const char* fmt, ...) __attribute__ ((format (printf, 1, 2)))
```

When I compile with `-Wformat` or `-Wall`, This complains about:

```
error: format string argument not a string type
```

I recalled that a class method declaration has an implicit `this` parameter, so I changed the locations of the parameters to 2, 3:

```
inline void debug(const char* fmt, ...) __attribute__ ((format (printf, 2, 3)))
```

and now it compiles, but it looks like the parameters are shifted, as if the `this` parameter were being treated as part of the argument list.

How can I tell the function that `this` isn't part of the string that I want to print?

Comment: Can you use variadic templates? If so, you can make a [type safe printf](http://www.generic-programming.org/~dgregor/cpp/variadic-templates.html)

Comment: Don't think too much about `this`. It's not an explicit argument, period. Just follow the GCC manual, which says that for member functions you have to add 1 to the `format`-attribute arguments. It's just an opaque rule, given to you by the vendor of a compiler extension.

Comment: printf (2, 3) is right. Define "seems like shifted"...?

Comment: The `format` attribute specifies style of the format string, the argument location of the format string, and the argument location of the `...`. The compiler then uses that information to do type checking of the `...` arguments with the format string.

Comment: Uh! And even with gcc 6.2 the error is still as cryptic...

Comment: I got the same error when i added __ attribute __ after the semicolon. Later i realized this error and added semicolon after attribute declaration. Strange!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You've done it.  `this` is argument 1, so by saying `format(printf, 2, 3)` you're telling the compiler that you're NOT printing `this`, you're printing argument 2 (`fmt`) with additional arguments past that.

Comment: It makes sense but I wonder why this is not documented anywhere

Comment: you are right [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes): **Since non-static C++ methods have an implicit this argument, the arguments of such methods should be counted from two, not one, when giving values for string-index and first-to-check.**

Answer (score 6):

Treat static members the same as non-members.  The discussion gave me the answer, but it's worth noting for others:

- non-member functions work with 1,2
- **static** member functions work with 1,2
- **non-static** member functions treat 'this' as #1, so need 2,3

I found this because we have some processes that use log helpers like this and 1 out of 4 was requiring `__attribute__ (( format( printf, 2, 3 ) ))` with the other three working well with `__attribute__ (( format(printf, 1, 2) ))` - turned out it was non-static...

Answer (score 6):

[@Chris Dodd is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11621112/4561887).

Use:

```cpp
inline void debug(const char* fmt, ...) __attribute__ ((format (printf, 2, 3)));
```

Since `debug()` is a C++ class member function, the first argument to it is automatically implicitly the class's `this` argument. So, using `(printf, 2, 3)` says that `2` is the format string **string-index**, which means that the second argument (ie: the first argument after `this`) is the format string, and the `3` is the **first-to-check** argument, which means the 3rd arguments is the first value which gets substituted into the format string.

Here's the latest gcc documentation to back it up (thanks [Foxit reader](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf-reader/) for letting me mark up PDFs on Linux). Pay special attention to the part marked in green in the image below.

> Since non-static C++ methods have an implicit `this` argument, the arguments of such methods should be counted from **two**, not one, when giving values for *string-index* and *first-to-check*.

**Source**:

1. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes (see the section titled "format (archetype, string-index, first-to-check)").
2. Latest documentation: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes

**Image** (esp. see highlighting in green):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since it only works for gcc, it would be good to define it this way to avoid errors on other compilers.

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
          __attribute__ (( format( printf, 2, 3 ) ))
#endif
```

Comment: That's a good point in general, but it's not an issue for me, as this is an internal code base built using a strict flow.

Comment: You could also use `#ifndef __GNUC__ #define __attribute__(a)`. Then you can use any attribute.

Comment: It works for clang too, actually, which is, by design, gcc compatible. "It is designed to act as a drop-in replacement for the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC), supporting most of its compilation flags and unofficial language extensions." ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang)).