# What's the right way to reference a parameter in Doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

I have the following Doxygen documentation for a function:

```
/**
  @brief Does interesting things

  @param[in]  pfirst The first parameter: a barrel full of monkeys

  @pre
    "pfirst" must have been previously passed through BarrelFiller()
*/
```

Note that `pfirst` is a parameter, and that it is referenced in the preconditions.

I've surrounded it with quotation marks here because I want to stand it off from the rest of the text. But it would be nice to do this in such a way that Doxygen will highlight the command and, preferably, link it to the parameter definition. Is there a way to do this?

It would be especially nice if this would happen using only the default configuration (or minor alterations thereof).

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Doxygen provides the command [`\p`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdp) for indicating that the next word is a parameter to the function. You would use it like so:

```
... the \p x and \p y coordinates are used to ...
```

I believe by default this will be represented using a typewriter font. I don't think this currently provides any auto-linking functionality, but potentially could in the future.

There is a related command, [`\a`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmda) that is used to mark up member arguments. By default, it is displayed with emphasis in the text (`<em>arg</em>`)

You can find more information about the various Doxygen [Special Commands reference](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html).

Comment: I think this is not _exactly_ what OP is asking about (although by no means I presume I know better than him regarding his own question). Mostly what he's asking is how to markup some text in such a manner that the output will be _semantically_ marked up as a parameter (for example, in HTML output, an element which is member of the `paramname` class), not only _rendered similarly_ as parameters in the default stylesheet. This is obviously important if you're skinning Doxygen's output, but currently there's no affordable way to do it.

Comment: Even if you want the output to identify parameters using an HTML class, you'd still use the '\p' or '\a' markup in the source code comments - as these tell Doxygen your intent.  How it renders these tokens in the output is a separate matter - whether '<tt>' etc or as a class.  How to make Doxygen do this is another matter - perhaps look at the XML output.

Comment: For utmost clarity for anyone landing here who did not yet notice this clause in the Doxygen documentation: you can substitute any command's leading `\ ` with a `@` and get the same results. So, `@p` would also work here.

Answer (score 11):

I know you're asking about `@param`eters, but Google searches lead here for `@return` types too, so here's that answer:

### Doxygen `#` usage in front of return value to create hyperlink to its definition:

Use the `#` symbol.

Full Example (**see the `@return` types just below with a `#` in front of each of them**):

```c
#include <stdarg.h> // for va_list, va_start, va_end
#include <stdio.h>  // for vsnprintf

// Function prototype:

int debug_printf(const char *format, ...) __attribute__((format(printf, 1, 2)));

// Function definition:

/// @brief      Function to print out data through serial UART for debugging.
/// @details    Feel free to add more details here,
///             perhaps
///             even
///             a
///             whole
///             paragraph.
/// @note       Optionally add a note too.
/// @param[in]  format  `printf`-like format string
/// @param[in]  ...     `printf`-like variadic list of arguments corresponding 
///                 to the format string
/// @return     Number of characters printed if OK, or < 0 if error:
///             - #DEBUG_ERR_ENCODING
///             - #DEBUG_ERR_OVERFLOW
///             - #DEBUG_ERR_UART
int debug_printf(const char *format, ...)
{
    int num_chars_printed;

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);

    // Use `vsnprintf()` now here to format everything into a single string
    // buffer, then send out over the UART
    // - num_chars_printed could be set to one of the error codes listed above
    //   here

    va_end(args);

    return num_chars_printed;
}
```

The Doxygen output now shows the error return types as a list of sub-bullets under the line `Number of characters printed if OK, or < 0 if error:`, **and each of the error types is turned into a URL to their respective definitions due to the `#` character in front**.

### Doxygen References:

1. See [@Jeremy Sarao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43813533/4561887), and tribal knowledge running around my head.
2. Tribal knowledge. I have no idea how or where to find this info. in Doxygen documentation.

   - Maybe this is useful? http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/autolink.html
3. **See a list of all of Doxygen's special commands here: http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html (ex: `\brief` or `@brief`, `\note` or `@note`, `\details` or `@details`, `\example`, etc.).**
4. Note that possible `param` values are **`param[in]`**, **`param[in,out]`**, and **`param[out]`**. See these references for more details & official documentation:

   1. [Is that an in or in/out parameter? Doxygen, C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47732665/is-that-an-in-or-in-out-parameter-doxygen-c/47856215#47856215)
   2. Official Doxygen documentation for the `param` special command: http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdparam
5. Other code examples demonstrating Doxygen usage:

   1. [STM32 how to get last reset status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34196663/stm32-how-to-get-last-reset-status/54728664#54728664)
   2. [Error handling in C code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385975/error-handling-in-c-code/59221452#59221452)

### Other References:

1. Documentation for GCC's super useful printf format attribute:

   1. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html - see "format" section
   2. [How to use formatting strings in user-defined functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54878841/how-to-use-formatting-strings-in-user-defined-functions/54916870#54916870)
   3. [How should I properly use __attribute__ ((format (printf, x, y))) inside a class method in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621043/how-should-i-properly-use-attribute-format-printf-x-y-inside-a-class/54191459#54191459)
2. Basic `printf` wrapper implementation: https://github.com/adafruit/ArduinoCore-samd/blob/master/cores/arduino/Print.cpp#L189

### Other Doxygen Examples:

(Copied from [my eRCaGuy_dotfiles project here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/git%20%26%20Linux%20cmds%2C%20help%2C%20tips%20%26%20tricks%20-%20Gabriel.txt))

Full Doxygen function header example:

```c
/// \brief          A brief one or two line description of the function.
/// \note           An important note the user should be aware of--perhaps many 
///                 lines.
/// \details        Extra details.
///                 Perhaps
///                 even
///                 a long
///                 paragraph.
/// \param[in]      var1            Description of variable one, an input
/// \param[in]      var2            Description of variable two, an input
/// \param[out]     var3            Description of variable three, an output 
///                     (usu. via a pointer to a variable)
/// \param[in,out]  var4            Description of variable four, an 
///                     input/output (usu. via a pointer) since its initial 
///                     value is read and used, but then it is also updated by 
///                     the function at some point
/// \return         Description of return types. It may be an enum, with these
///                 possible values:
///                 - #ENUM_VALUE_1
///                 - #ENUM_VALUE_2
///                 - #ENUM_VALUE_3
my_enum_t myFunc(int var1, int var2, int* var3, int* var4)
{
    // function implementation here
    
    my_enum_t error = ENUM_VALUE_1;
    
    // Check for NULL pointers
    if (!var3 || !var4)
    {
        // var3 or var4 are NULL pointers, which means they can't be
        // dereferenced
        error = ENUM_VALUE_2;
        goto done;
    }

    if (something_else)
    {
        error = ENUM_VALUE_3;
        goto done;
    }

done:
    return error;
}
```

You may also use `@` instead of `\`:

```c
/// @brief          A brief one or two line description of the function.
/// @param[in]      var1            Description of variable one, an input
/// @param[in]      var2            Description of variable two, an input
/// @param[out]     var3            Description of variable three, an output 
///                     (usu. via a pointer to a variable)
/// @param[in,out]  var4            Description of variable four, an 
///                     input/output (usu. via a pointer) since its initial 
///                     value is read and used, but then it is also updated by 
///                     the function at some point
/// @return         None
void myFunc(int var1, int var2, int* var3, int* var4)
{
    // function implementation here
}
```

And here's this shorter version again now with `\` again instead of `@`:

```c
/// \brief          A brief one or two line description of the function.
/// \param[in]      var1            Description of variable one, an input
/// \param[in]      var2            Description of variable two, an input
/// \param[out]     var3            Description of variable three, an output (
///                     usu. via a pointer to a variable)
/// \param[in,out]  var4            Description of variable four, an 
///                     input/output (usu. via a pointer) since its initial 
///                     value is read and used, but then it is also updated by 
///                     the function at some point
/// \return         None
void myFunc(int var1, int var2, int* var3, int* var4)
{
    // function implementation here
}
```

Comment: I find the way you nicely indent everything aesthetically pleasing, but oh man, it's such a pain to maintain that by hand. Do you happen to know of any Doxygen auto-formatting tools that could help with this?

Comment: @303, I don't. For normal comment blocks, I can hard wrap a comment block to my first column-width "rulers" setting in Sublime Text by pressing Alt + Q. However, for Doxygen comments, my approach is to simply go to [my notes file here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/git%20%26%20Linux%20cmds%2C%20help%2C%20tips%20%26%20tricks%20-%20Gabriel.txt#L233-L346) and manually copy-paste a Doxygen header from there to my code, then update it manually. I do this all the time. I keep this notes doc open and just copy-paste a new Doxygen header from it whenever needed.

Comment: @303, update: Eclipse, one of the main IDEs I use in conjunction with Sublime Text 4, has a feature where if you press Return on a line with 3 Doxygen slashes it automatically adds 3 slashes for Doxygen to the new line. This is convenient and saves a tiny bit of time and work. Then, with just a few tabs, I can continue typing at the desired level of indentation.

Answer (score 1):

use the "#" symbol in front of the parameter you want to reference:

```
#pfirst must have been previously passed through BarrelFiller()
```

([in the doxygen manual](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/autolink.html#linkother))

Comment: `#` is used to refer member variables, not function parameters.

Comment: Wrong answer. If `pfirst` is a parameter, this yields a "warning: explicit link request to pfirst' could not be resolved" and the hash is written literally in the generated documentation. Output is a fancy link if `pfirst` is a member function or variable.

Comment: +1 because the `#` symbol works in front of `@return` types (values) to create links to the definition of each return value, which is what I actually wanted to know. Ex: `/// @return  Number of characters printed, or < 0 if error: #OVERFLOW or #UART`. Now, in my generated Doxygen, "OVERFLOW" and "UART" are shown as hyperlinks to their respective definitions, which is great.

Comment: And I decided to write it as an answer since even though it's not an answer to the OP's question exactly, it's related, and Google searches for return types lead here too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56745246/4561887