# What's the right way to reference a template parameters in Doxygen?

Tags: c++, templates, doxygen

A follow-up question to:

[What's the right way to reference a parameter in Doxygen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398711/whats-the-right-way-to-reference-a-parameter-in-doxygen)

So, for parameters, we use `@param`

```
@param my_param the quick brown fox takes this parameter over the lazy dog
```

and then we can refer to it using `@p`:

```
@param my_other_param this is completely different from @p my_param , you know!
```

Now, for template parameters, I would replace `@param` with `@tparam`. What should replace the `@p`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@p` doesn't *really* "reference" a parameter; it just styles the next word in typewriter font. You will generally use that to reference parameters, but `@p` doesn't do anything special beyond using typewriter font for the next word.

So you can use `@p` to style a template parameter if you like. Or you could use `@a`. Or something else. It's all up to the way you want the results to look.

Answer (score -1):

To create a reference a another symbol use the @ref command.  However this command does not work for parameters.  Doxygen does not recognize them as a target of the @ref.